# Displaying PDF in my Android app

Tags: android, pdf, android-file

I am developing an Android app and currently I am downloading a PDF file which I got from external web service. Now I want to display the PDF inside the application using PDF viewer without saving to the device memory.

Is it possible? If it isn't, then is it possible to save a PDF file to the device with password protected?

Comment: `without downloading` and `which I got through from external web service` fight... so you downloaded it from a web service.

Comment: No... I get the byte array from a web-service call.

Comment: ... which is **offline**, in your opinion? Will it work without a web connection? So, you see, you are **receiving** (= **downloading**) data through the network.

Comment: I get the byte array from a web service call and I want to display that byte array without downloading the pdf file to the device. Is that possible ?

Comment: This all makes no sense to me too. Is the content of that pdf file in the 'pdf file byte array` ? If not then what is a 'pdf file byte array'?

Comment: I guess you know that calling a webservice and **getting data through the network** actually means **downloading**. That said, just use a library (muPdf or any other) to open your pdf.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect description. I get the pdf from the web service as byte array. My client does't want to download pdf byte array to pdf file into device memory. So with out downloading the pdf byte array as a pdf is it possible to display the pdf from the pdf byte array.

Comment: @Arun I tried to clarify your issue. Feel free to revert/edit/improve it.

Comment: @AndrewT. Is this possible ?

Comment: Last time I tried, I could display it using 3rd-party library, but the performance was appalling. However, I haven't tried [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/), so you may consider to try that, as I heard that it was okay from my colleague.

Comment: I tried MuPDF but it is very slow